# I am not able to access my Wordpress site in remote WAMP server because my IP address has been changed

Tags: php, wordpress, wampserver, remote-access

I have kept my WAMP server in remote so that everyone in my network can access my wordpress site but as my IP address has been changed no one can access it. They can open the site with new IP but the site content are not displayed properly.I am not able to access it fully.
please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the IP in the "wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini"

Comment: dear hearner there is no sentence to change the ip address i tried finding my old ip using ctrl + f but it says cannot find..what to do

Comment: Read the [Wordpress doc on changing the domain name](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) because that is basically what you have done

Comment: dear riggs i have read the doc and succeed 90% but not able to get the same view as previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I got the answer to the question. Thanks any way
First take the back up of your database than click on wp_option and change the site url1 to the one you want and also change the home to the one you want. and than save the database to your local computer and right click and open in any editor and replace the old url to the one you want.
e.g in my case the old one was 192.168.0.110 so I changed it to
http://192.168.0.114/
you can do this with find and replace by pressing ctrl+f

Comment: If you are doing a global search and replace for the ip address in the database be very careful - as a lot of times it will be saved as part of a serialized string. Fortunately your two ip address are the same number of characters, but if they were not then that would have broken the site :)

Editing siteurl and home under the _options table is fine - once you do that I would then use a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ to update any other references on your site.